# Can't send data to in angular 5 components.ts file to html file?

Tags: angular

I have a problem like this. I am developing a simple angular app. I am retrieving data from the database. For that, I have created a service.ts file like this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Employee } from './employee';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
  selectedEmployee: Employee;
  public  employees: Employee[];
  readonly baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/employees';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postEmployee(employee: Employee) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL, employee);
  }

  getEmployeeList() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL);
  }

}
```

And in the components file, I have coded like this to call this function in the service.ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import { EmployeeService } from '../shared/employee.service';
import { Employee } from '../shared/employee';

declare var M: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css'],
  providers: [EmployeeService]
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
    this.refreshEmployeeList();
  }

  refreshEmployeeList() {
    this.employeeService.getEmployeeList().subscribe(function (res) {
      this.employeeService.employees = res as Employee[];
    });
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form) {
      form.reset();
      this.employeeService.selectedEmployee = {
        _id: '',
        name: '',
        position: '',
        office: '',
        salary: null
      };
    }
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.value._id === '') {
      this.employeeService.postEmployee(form.value).subscribe((res) => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        M.toast({ html: 'Saved successfully', classes: 'rounded' });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

If I replace

```
this.employeeService.employees = res as Employee[];
```

This as

```
console.log(res);
```

It prints the all the data in the database correctly in the console window but with this.employeeService.employees = res as Employee[] line it is giving me an error like this.

> core.js:1449 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'employees' of
>   undefined
>           at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (employee.component.ts:26)
>           at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:243)
>           at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:190)
>           at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:131)
>           at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
>           at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
>           at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
>           at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:90)
>           at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
>           at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:151)

This is my HTML file.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m6">
    <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s5">

          </div>
          <div class="col s7">
            <table class="responsive-table highLight">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Position</th>
                  <th>Office</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tr *ngFor="let emp of employees">
                <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.position}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.office}}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what is the problem with my code?. Can someone help me to solve this problem?. I Look some examples, questions, and answers. They were not enough me to solve this problem. Thank You

Comment: make the changes suggested by @cgTag and use `ngFor = let emp of employeeService.employees` in your Template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the word `function` and use `(res) =>`

```
this.employeeService.getEmployeeList().subscribe((res) => {
  this.employeeService.employees = res as Employee[];
});
```

The `this` was not the current component.

When working with TypeScript it's better to use the `() =>` instead of `function ()` because the fat arrow persists the current reference to `this`

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are looping over employees in your html but there is no variable with name employees on the component class

You can say ngFor = let emp of employeeService.employees

Answer (score 0):

Creat new variable in the component.

```
employees : any;

refreshEmployeeList() { 
this.employeeService.getEmployeeList().subscribe(function (res) { 
this.employees = res;

});

 }
```

Then use employees in the html file

Comment: Thank you. It works. But nothing is showing in the view. how can I change my HTML file to get it done? I have updated the view file now in the question.

Comment: Use object.key method and  push data into employees and make final array of data then return employees.

Object.keys(res).forEach(function(key) { this.employees.push(res[key]) });

return this.employees;


Use above  code in the refreshEmployeeList method.

Comment: Use object.keys method and make final array employees and return that array.

Object.keys(res).forEach(function(key) { this.employees.push(res[key]); });

Return this.employees;

Use this code in the refreshEmployeeList method.

Comment: this.employeeService.getEmployeeList().subscribe(function (res) {
      Object.keys(res).forEach(function(key) { this.employees.push(res[key]); })
      return this.employees ;
    });

Comment: I put like this. But it is giving me the previous error again

Comment: Just print console.log(res[key].name) and check value is printed or not. If not then can you know me which type of reponse are you getting?